# Trouble with initializing mu4e: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "mu4e")

Tags: mu4e, email

I'm trying to read email inside emacs.

`mu` is installed via package manager from my linux-distro (arch) via : `yay -S mu`. And `mu` can be called from the shell/terminal.

---

1. When I evaluate `(require 'mu4e)`, in `emacs -Q` gives following error:

```elisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "mu4e")
  require(mu4e)
  (progn (require 'mu4e))
  (setq elisp--eval-defun-result (progn (require 'mu4e)))
  eval-region(146 161 t #f(compiled-function (ignore) #<bytecode 0x135f41a21b474eb2>))  ; Reading at buffer position 160
  elisp--eval-defun()
Adjusting your load-path shouldn't be necessary. Emacs should pre-populate load-path with the directories in /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/* (but you need to run doom refresh to ensure this new value for load-path is correctly cached).


  eval-defun(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-defun nil)
  call-interactively(eval-defun nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-defun)
```

After this, I can't `M-x mu4e` in `emacs -Q`

---

2. However, when I evaluate `(require 'mu4e)`, in `emacs` with my config gives following error:

```elisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function mu4e--main-action-str)
  mu4e--main-action-str("\11* [J]ump to some maildir\n" mu4e-jump-to-maildir)
  apply(mu4e--main-action-str ("\11* [J]ump to some maildir\n" mu4e-jump-to-maildir))
  evil-collection-mu4e--main-action-str("\11* [J]ump to some maildir\n" mu4e-jump-to-maildir)
  byte-code("\300\301\302\"\300\303\304\"\300\305\306\"Q\207" [evil-collection-mu4e--main-action-str "\11* [J]ump to some maildir\n" mu4e-jump-to-maildir "\11* enter a [s]earch query\n" mu4e-search "\11* [C]ompose a new message\n" mu4e-compose-new] 5)
  (defvar evil-collection-mu4e-new-region-basic (byte-code "\300\301\302\"\300\303\304\"\300\305\306\"Q\207" [evil-collection-mu4e--main-action-str "\11* [J]ump to some maildir\n" mu4e-jump-to-maildir "\11* enter a [s]earch query\n" mu4e-search "\11* [C]ompose a new message\n" mu4e-compose-new] 5) ("/home/garid/.config/emacs/elpa/evil-collection-202..." . 6456))
  require(evil-collection-mu4e "/home/garid/.config/emacs/elpa/evil-collection-202..." nil)
  evil-collection-require(mu4e)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4a45e8ea36c860f>)()
  eval-after-load-helper("/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e/mu4e.elc")
  run-hook-with-args(eval-after-load-helper "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e/mu4e.elc")
  do-after-load-evaluation("/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e/mu4e.elc")
  require(mu4e)
  (progn (require 'mu4e))
  (setq elisp--eval-defun-result (progn (require 'mu4e)))
  eval-region(1 16 t #f(compiled-function (ignore) #<bytecode 0x135fa1f34f69ceb2>))  ; Reading at buffer position 14
  elisp--eval-defun()
  eval-defun(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-defun nil)
  call-interactively(eval-defun nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-defun)
```

After this, I **CAN** `M-x mu4e` in `emacs`. And with full config below I can read my emails in emacs.

```elisp
(setq mu4e-maildir (expand-file-name "~/.local/share/mail/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"))

(setq mu4e-drafts-folder "/[Gmail]/Drafts")
(setq mu4e-sent-folder   "/[Gmail]/Sent Mail")
(setq mu4e-trash-folder  "/[Gmail]/Trash")

(setq mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)

(setq mu4e-maildir-shortcuts
      '(("/INBOX"             . ?i)
        ("/[Gmail]/Sent Mail" . ?s)
        ("/[Gmail]/Trash"     . ?t)))

(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap")
```

---

**Questions**:

- Why I'm getting error at `(require 'mu4e)` in both cases?
- And why I can execute `M-x mu4e` even after error (in my config)? (My config have no entry about `mu4e`)

Comment: The backtrace shows that the error is being triggered by something in your config named `evil-collection`, so I would take a look at that.  Maybe you need to update it or remove it.

Comment: @phils, you're right, without `evil collection` it doesn't give error. I think I need to somehow remove/turn of the mail part: `evil-collection-mu4e` from whole `evil-collection`.

Comment: Could you mind explain me why I got error in the `emacs -Q`?

Comment: `emacs -Q` prevents your init file or site-lisp libraries being loaded, so your `C-h v load-path` isn't set up for any non-standard libraries.  This is completely normal.  `emacs -Q` is for running a completely default Emacs that doesn't know about your config, so you would have to add to the `load-path` manually in that situation.

Comment: @phils, I see thanks

Comment: It seems like this is caused by recent update from `mu`. This guy had same error recently, `evil-collection` 's [github repo](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/issues/723). Hopefully this will fixed in future updates.

Comment: The double-hyphen in `mu4e--main-action-str` identifies it as intended for internal use only and therefore liable to change or disappear at any time, so ideally `evil-collection` wouldn't be calling it.  (I don't know what it's doing with it, and there may not have been an alternative, but if the latter then I'd recommend they talk to the `mu4e` maintainer about their use-case and the possibility of a stable API function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated all my packages:

Now `evil-collection` (version: `20230430.1927`) doesn't throw this error